# If $f:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is homomorphism, show that $f$ is monomorphism.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Here's the complete problem.

If $f:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is homomorphism such that $f(0,1)=(-1,5)$ and $f(1,0)=(2,-3)$, show that $f$ is monomorphism.

Need help at least a hint. I have no idea. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: What is $f(x,y)$?

Comment: $f(x,y)=(x,y)$?

Comment: Why would that be the case? Hint: $(x,y) = x(1,0) + y(0,1)$.

Comment: did you mean $f(x,y) = x(1,0)+y(0,1)$?

Comment: No, I meant exactly what I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Prove the kernel is trivial.  That is, $f(x,y)=(0,0)\implies (x,y)=(0,0)$.

Further hint:  $f(x,y)=f(x(1,0)+y(0,1))=f(x(1,0))+f(y(0,1))=xf(1,0)+yf(0,1)=x(2,-3)+y(-1,5)=(2x-y,-3x+5y)$.

Comment: what can I do for define $f$?

Comment: Using @Arturo's comment, $f(x,y)=y(-1,5)+x(2,-3)$

Comment: See the hint given Arturo Magidin above. Does that help you in computing, for instance $f(2,3)$?

Comment: @Shahab $f(2,3)=2(1,0)+3(0,1)=(2,0)+(0,3)=(2,3)$. Right?

Comment: Wrong: $f(2,3)=f(2(1,0)+3(0,1))=2f(1,0)+3f(0,1)=\cdots$.

Comment: No.  You;re forgetting $f$.  It's $f(2.3)=f(2(1,0)+3(0,1))=2f(1,0)+3f(0,1)=2(2,-3)+3(-1,5)=(1,9)$.

Comment: Oh, see. Thus, $f$ can defined by $f(x,y)=x(1,0)+y(0,1)$ right?

Comment: You forgot to apply $f$ to $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ again.  You're not using the homomorphism property.

Comment: it's $f(x,y)=f(x(1,0)+y(0,1))$, right?

Comment: Yes.  Now see my edit, please.

Comment: how can $f(x(1,0))+f(y(0,1))=xf(1,0)+yf(0,1)$?

Comment: That's a good question.  Remember $x(1,0)=(1,0)+\dots+(1,0)$, with $x$ summands of $(1,0)$.

Comment: ok, and then, whats next?

Comment: The homomorphism property:  $f((1,0)+\dots+(1,0))=f(1,0)+\dots+f(1,0)$.

Comment: oh, great. i see that. thanks for help bro!

Comment: Sure.  Glad you got it.